# How to click a checkbox if only value is different for each row

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I have a problem how to click a desired checkbox if only value is different for each row.
Here is a code for a first row with 'Access all mailbox':
[image: Only value for row is different]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your particular test case? What you have marked is a hidden input. It is not a check-box. Just some value that would be sent to server when you submit your choice.

Comment: I have to click on the required checkbox.
But all the rows have the same code and only the value is different.

Comment: I am not getting you. How do you define the `required` checkbox? This really matters. Can you described your particular testcase as if it would be manual?

Comment: @Majkl use the sibling xpath for example //td[contains(text(), 'Access all mailboxes')]/../following-sibling:://input[@id='allow']

Comment: @AlexeyR.
example of manual test case:
1. click first checkbox for Allow
2. click second checkbox for Allow
3. click on Apply button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **ID's must be unique in a web page**

  So all checkbox should have different ID's in this case. You can click on particular checkbox using `//td[@id='allow']/input`
- If you want to select the checkbox based on like *Access all mailbox* , *Apply tags* and so on then you can used below xpath

  ```
    //table[@id='permRoles']//td[contains(.,'Access all mailboxes')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input
  ```

Comment: This solution works as expected. Thank you very much, guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is where [Page Objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) come to the rescue.

You will need to break the table into its components and use dependency injection (in this case, I like to call it, *location injection*):

- The table itself;
- A row.

The table will now how to identify itself and each individual row and how to select rows given some criteria:

```
Table {

   baseLocator = "MyTableLocator";
   rowLocator = "MyRowLocator";

   getRowByPermCodeValue(String permCodeValue) {

      for(row : this.getAllRows() {
         if(row.getPermCode() == permCodeValue) {
            return row
         }
      }
      throw Exception(...)
   }

   // Creates a list of Row objects, described below
   getAllRows() {
      return baseLocator.findElements(rowLocator).map(rowBaseLocator => new Row(rowBaseLocator));
   }

}
```

A row will know how inspect elements inside itself, but will need to know how to locate itself:

```
Row {

   permCodeLocator = "PermCodeLocator"
   allowCheckBoxLocator = "AllowCheckboxLocator"

   // This is where the location dependency happens
   // Each individual row doesn't need to know how to locate itself
   // The table will indicate it, and the row will know to locate its 
   // components inside the specific branch of the DOM
   Row(rowBaseLocator) {
      this.rowBaseLocator= rowBaseLocator;
   }

   getPermCode() {
      return this.rowBaseLocator.findElement(this.permCodeLocator).getText();
   }

   checkAllow() {
      this.rowBaseLocator.findElement(this.allowCheckBoxLocator);
   }
}
```

Your test would do something like:

```
new Table().getRowByPermCodeValue("123456").checkAllow()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approaches like this:

- Use xPath to locate check-box by index (if yon need Nth check-box): `(//td[@id='allow']/input[@type='checkbox'])[1]`. Where you can change the index of the element. For example to check `allow` check-box on the 2nd line you use `(//td[@id='allow']/input[@type='checkbox'])[2]`
- Get a list of `IWebElement` using `FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@id='allow']/input[@type='checkbox']"))` method and then iterate through all the items if you need to check the check-boxes for all the items
- If you need the check-box against some particular text you also can use the labels provided for your check-boxes. See below.

For example you can use this xpath to check `allow` check-box against `Apply tags` label:

```
//tr[normalize-space(./td[@id='role'])='Apply tags']/td[@id='allow']/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Or eventually if you still need to pick a check-box by that `value` attribute (however I believe this is not you do really need):

```
//tr[./td/input[@value='398220']]/td[@id='allow']/input[@type='checkbox']
```